# finding a formula involving an excise tax

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, economics

this is based off of Anthony and Brigg's Mathematics For Economics And Finance: Methods And Modeling.

it's exercise 1.5 on pg 11.

the question reads, "Find a formula for the amount of money the government obtains from taxing the commodity in the manner described in exercise 1.4. Determine this quantity explicitly when T=0.5."

i'll give you the required equations:

qS = 6p - 12
qD = 40 - 2p

the excise tax = pT = (13/2)+(3/4)T

the answer = 27T - (3/2)T^2

i have no clue how they came up with that answer. i got 27 + (9/2)T.

my process was to substitute the value of pT into qS.

i also tried putting pT-T into qS, which gets me 27 + (3/2)T, close but not exactly the answer.

also, i just followed the example in the book so i don't really have a conceptual understanding of the why, so can someone explain the logic behind inserting pT-T vs pT into qS?

here's the link for the book [Mathematics for Economics and Finance: Methods and Modelling - Martin Anthony, Norman Biggs - Google Books](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=H1WMAFtCDwsC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)

the question's on page 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without tax
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Demand}\quad D:\quad & &q+2p&=40\\
\text{Supply}\quad S:\quad & &q-6p&=-12
\end{align}
$$
that is the equilibrium is $$(p_e, q_e)=\left(\frac{13}{2},27\right)$$
With tax $T$
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Demand}\quad D^T:\quad & &q^T+2p^T&=40\\
\text{Supply}\quad S^T:\quad & &q^T-6(p^T-T)&=-12
\end{align}
$$
that is the equilibrium after tax is 
$$
(p^T_e,q^T_e)=\left(\frac{13}{2}+\frac{3}{4}T,\;27-\frac{3}{2}T\right)=\left(p_e+\frac{3}{4}T,\;q_e-\frac{3}{2}T\right)
$$
We see that $p_e^T>p_e$ and $q^T_e<q_e$.
So the government revenue is
$$
GR=T\times q^T_e=T\times \left(27-\frac{3}{2}T\right)=27 T-\frac{3}{2}T^2
$$
and for $T=0.5$ we have $$
GR\big|_{T=0.5}=27 \times 0.5-\frac{3}{2}\times (0.5)^2=13.125
$$